# How to set the password of a cognito user as the admin?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Via the cognito admin API how do I set a users password? When a user is created I can set a temporary password, I need to be able to do this to an existing user.

Answer (score 17):

The newest version of the cognito api adds an action [AdminSetUserPassword](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminSetUserPassword.html) which has a request syntax like the following

```
{
   "Password": "string",
   "Permanent": boolean,
   "Username": "string",
   "UserPoolId": "string"
}
```

and will allow you to set a permanent or temporary password for a given user.

Comment: Finally a new API. Much needed.

Comment: Getting error while using with Java SDK ---- Missing Authentication Token (Service: AWSCognitoIdentityProvider; Status Code: 400; Error Code: MissingAuthenticationTokenException; Request ID: 91179a62-1754-4cc4-9dee-623fc6f7929c; Proxy: null)

Comment: @AnujSharma did you found any solution to this? I'm having the same issue and i don't know which key should i use. Thanks!

Comment: I had different keys stored in my local system which was causing this authentication issue. I deleted from my environment variables and then it was working fine.

Answer (score 8):

EDIT-2: The newest version of cognito API now supports [AdminSetUserPassword](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminSetUserPassword.html).

You can't set a users password, the only thing you can do is use [AdminResetUserPassword](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminResetUserPassword.html).

EDIT: You can call [ForgotPassword](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_ForgotPassword.html) too. But as the name suggests this is supposed to be called by a user, not an admin.

Answer (score 0):

The latest of the Cognito API gives us  [AdminSetUserPassword](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminSetUserPassword.html#CognitoUserPools-AdminSetUserPassword-request-Permanent) which has a body of this kind

```
{
   "Password": "string",
   "Permanent": boolean,
   "Username": "string",
   "UserPoolId": "string"
}
```

using this you can set a password for a user considering yourself as an admin. You can get the UserPoolId from the Cognito user pools home page.

Headers goes as this :

```
 X-Amz-Target: AWSCognitoIdentityProviderService.AdminSetUserPassword
 Content-Type: application/x-amz-json-1.1
```

If you face any errors, kindly refer to this page for available headers: [Making API Requests](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/transfer/latest/userguide/making-api-requests.html)